# Command line opening of Atom triggering Windows command prompt

Tags: windows, git, bash, terminal, atom-editor

My normal routine for opening up a project in the Atom editor on Windows is to go to the directory using the Git Bash terminal and typing `atom .` This opens the entire contents of the directory in Atom.

After a recent Windows update, when I type `atom .` I now see this:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Web\htdocs\dev>
```

This is a flashing command prompt. Is the base Windows command prompt taking over from the Git Bash terminal I'm using?

When I input just `atom` in the terminal the Atom editor opens as normal.

When I input `explorer .` it works just fine (opens an explorer window in the current directory).

When I open Windows PowerShell and input `atom .` the correct behavior happens.

When I run git-cmd.exe and input `atom .` the correct behavior happens.

---

This is a known issue with Atom: https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/11817

Running `atom.cmd .` will produce the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd comment but don't have enough reputation.

I started experiencing the same thing this morning, but haven't updated my Windows 10 for over a week.
If you open:

`C:\Program Files\Git\git-cmd.exe`

it works fine. So I think it's actually mintty.exe (C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin), the terminal app that runs when you open Git Bash. My current version of mintty is 2.0.3.

UPDATE: Looks like this is tied to today's update of atom: https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/11817

UPDATE 2 - TEMPORARY SOLUTION: add this alias to your .bashrc or aliases file:

`alias atom='atom.cmd'`

Should do the trick until the good people at Atom release a fix.

Comment: Yep, I'm seeing the proper behavior when running git-cmd.exe as well. But something's getting lost along the way. And I'm on Windows 7 by the way. Recent update must have done something.

Comment: My C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\atom\bin\atom.cmd file, which is what the PATH points to, shows modified this morning @ 8:36. How about yours?

Comment: Looks like this is tied to today's update of atom:
https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/11817

Comment: Sweet! Thanks for hunting that down. I went into the Beta channel to see if that would clear anything up and it did not.

Comment: If you edit your answer with that bug comment I will mark that as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest two steps:

1. Check your git configs to make sure atom is still your default editor: `git config -l`. If it isn't, set it with `git config --global core.editor "atom --wait"`.
2. You may need to create a new path for atom, depending on where you installed it.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I added a couple things to my initial question. I think it gives me a better idea that it's a Git Bash problem.

Comment: Ah, I see. Have you checked the version of Git Bash since updating your OS?

Comment: Good call, just upgraded Git to 2.8.3 and rebooted and seeing the same.

Comment: I think the path could be set for PowerShell, but not for Git Bash. Are you familiar with how to check and set this?

Comment: I've been playing with my path as well and everything seems good since the basic `atom` command runs. So it seems like the path is picking it up, it's just when I add that pesky `.` to try to open the entire folder it breaks down.

Comment: Just to clarify, `atom` and `atom .` work from PowerShell, and `atom` works from Bash, but `atom .` doesn't work from Bash? Does more specific file naming work, like `atom index.html`?

Comment: Looks like we found the culprit! https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/11817 Thanks for your debugging!

Comment: Fantastic!  Thanks for sharing the answer